# Micro-ORM for .Net 2.0?

Tags: c#, orm, asp.net-2.0

Am writing a new C# web forms app and there is a strong possibility it will be deployed on a web server that only supports .Net 2.0.

I'd love to be able to use something like Dapper or PetaPoco for data access and manipulation, but it appears they both have requirements for .Net 3.0 or higher.

Are there similar alternatives that work on .Net 2.0?

I'm aware of SubSonic and NHibernate, but I really am only looking for something to query the DB and quickly stuff the results in POCOs.

Thanks!

Comment: Would love to upgrade. But it hosts some business critical apps so the boss is not too keen on upgrading and potentially breaking something.

Comment: Dapper does have some 3.0 support. I haven't tried it on 2.0, and to be honest I haven't event thought about what bits wouldn't work... But it could work, probably. What compiler version do you have, out of curiosity? (you can target .net 2.0 from most compiler versions)

Comment: Tried installing Dapper from NuGet and it told me that it wasn't compatible with 2.0. Also tried PetaPoco, but it threw all kinds of errors because of its Linq dependencies.

Has anyone had instances of installing .Net 4 where it broke their 2.0 apps?

Starting to think my safest bet might be to just use DbDataReader and DbCommand, make a couple helper methods, and manually stuff the POCOs and collections.

Comment: I guess it depends how much LINQ we've used, and how much could easily be replaced with non-LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find one that worked well in .Net 2.0 environment. Will be writing the app for 4.0 and deploying on a different server.

Comment: No need for that - you can isntall .net 4.0 separately and select version PER APPLICATION POOL. As in: one can run the 2.0 stuff, the other the 4.0 framework.

Comment: Actually, there is a need for that. When the original server was spec'd it was only given a 12GB OS Partition. There isn't sufficient disk space on the primary partition to install .Net 4. Luckily, there haven't been any new Service Packs for the OS :)

We will actually be replacing the server this year, so for now it makes sense to deploy the app on the other server.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Simple.Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data) or [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

I'm in the process of building a WCF service using Dapper and can recommend it.

EDIT: Arrgh, just noticed the 2.0 thing, both of these require 4. See if you can update!

Comment: Dapper doesn't require 4.0 - there's a 3.0 build IIRC

Comment: Really, I thought it used c# 4.0 dynamics?

Comment: the c# 3 build doesnt include the non-generic Query method (although we could probably return some kind of dictionary instead), and replaces a few other "dynamic" uses with "object"

Answer (score 0):

[LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) is an option. Works with 2.0 and the templates it uses are flexibile enough to generate POCO-like classes. It's not free, however.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not looking for code-generation, active record type stuff. I have MyGeneration and some templates for that sort of thing. This DB is a little more complex and what I'm using it for requires many complex joins. All I need is a simple DAL that allows me to query the DB and stuff the results into some POCOs. Maybe my best best is to just create a couple helper methods to take results from a reader and stuff them into POCOs.

Answer (score 0):

[`PetaPoco`](https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/blob/master/PetaPoco/PetaPoco.cs) supports .net 3.5 just add the following line at the PetaPoco.cs file above using statements:

```
#define PETAPOCO_NO_DYNAMIC
```